# How to see all details of a type in VSCode popup when hovering over variable

Tags: typescript, visual-studio-code

When hoovering over a TypeScript variable in VSCode a popup shows the type definition.
When the type is complex, the popup does not show all of the definition but rather uses an ellipsis sign to shorten the content. How can I see the complete definition of a type?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is not yet possible
(see https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/94679)